# Is there any saying or idiom to describe the opposite of “blessing in disguise”?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

Something that looks like a good thing at first, but has unforeseen bad consequences.

For instance, while irrigation schemes provide people with water for agriculture, they can increase waterborne diseases that have devastating health effects, such as schistosomiasis. (From wikipedia)

---

<sub>Major edit in body to provide a better example as requested in the comments. Saeid, please let us know if you disagree and this conflicts with your intent. -T.R.</sub>

Comment: The example you quote is not the opposite of a 'blessing in disguise'. A blessing in disguise is when something seeming bad happens but it turns out to be good. In this example something bad happened - a car service didn't show up - and it turned out to be worse.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch to say he was killed "because the car service... didn't show up."  Failure of one service to show did not cause a traffic accident.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you want the example edited to a more suitable one.

Comment: In your illustrative context, a *minor* misfortune (original taxi didn't show up) unexpectedly leads to a *major* misfortune (replacement has a fatal accident). Collins' definition for [***to top it all***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/to-top-it-all) seems apposite: *If you have been describing bad things that happened, and then say that **to top it all** something else happened, you mean that **the final thing was even worse**.*

Comment: How do you relate my example with  someone who  says: If I hadn't missed the flight, I would have been on that plane when it crashed:

Comment: I agree with DJClayworth and Tushar Raj that the Nash example isn't a very apt instance of a "curse in disguise." But I think that the question asked in the header and in the body of the question is more interesting than the question "What would you call a series of events of the type that befell John Forbes Nash, Jr?"

Comment: An opposite situation would be you're scheduled for a taxi cab, but instead the driver shows up with a limousine (at no extra charge), but then unfortunately, the limousine gets into an accident.

Comment: @Saeid Missing a flight (misfortune) and then not dying because of it (fortuitous) is a blessing in disguise. Getting a ticket to a flight that was supposed to be sold out when somebody cancels (fortuitous) and then dying in the crash (misfortune) would be the opposite. Hiring a taxicab after a car service not showing up is just solving your problem, not having something fortuitous happen to you.

Comment: Do you actually want the opposite of "blessing in disguise", or do you want a term to describe the event you describe?

Comment: @Catija I think the question should be edited to ask about "blessing in disguise" because that's what most of the answers answer; editing to the latter would invalidate most of the existing answers. If it turns out that OP wants a term to describe the event instead, it would be best posted as a new question now.

Comment: @TusharRaj, I think your edit imposes an opposite of the phrase that the OP did not intend. The answer presented by ScotM reconciled the original example with "opposite" of *blessing in disguise*.

Comment: @MorganHorse: Thanks. Hadn't seen Sven's answer. I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to respond. Majority of the answers, including the current topper (ipf's) are based on the assumption that the OP meant 'curse in disguise'. Seeing this, I'm not sure a rollback would help the post.

Answer (score 12):

In certain contexts, a **poisoned chalice** works.

> An assignment, award, or honour which is likely to prove a disadvantage or source of problems to the recipient: "many thought the new minister had been handed a poisoned chalice" (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poisoned-chalice)

When something is a curse in disguise (in the disguise of a blessing), you can also simply say that something is **more of a curse than a blessing**.

Comment: Similarly, alluding to the fairy tale of Snow White, people sometimes speak of a "poison apple."

Comment: I'm confused how this fits the OP's description at all... An "award" is a **positive** thing... your transportation failing to arrive is a **negative** thing. I would agree that it does answer the "opposite" of  "blessing in disguise", it does not fit what the OP is *actually* asking for in the content of the question, though.

Comment: Yes. It has a more general application; Wikipedia makes this sense clear: 'The term "poisoned chalice" is applied to a thing or situation which appears to be good when it is received or experienced by someone, but then becomes or is found to be bad.'

Answer (score 8):

A **'curse in disguise'** is the literal opposite, and [isn't unheard-of](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=curse%20in%20disguise&tbm=bks). As in:

- King Midas' gift of turning everything he touched to gold was a curse in disguise.

---

The phrase **[be careful what you wish for](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/be+careful+what+you+wish+for.html)** also comes to mind <sub>(Usingenglish.com)</sub>

> If you get things that you desire, there may be unforeseen and unpleasant consequences.
> ('Be careful what you wish for, lest it come true.' and 'Be careful what you wish for; you may receive it.' are also used.)

---

Also see, this wikipedia entry on [unintended consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences):

> *Unexpected drawback*: A negative, unexpected detriment occurring in addition to the desired effect of the policy (e.g., while irrigation schemes provide people with water for agriculture, they can increase waterborne diseases that have devastating health effects, such as schistosomiasis).
>
> ... In CIA jargon, "**blowback**" describes the unintended, undesirable consequences of covert operations,

**[Blowback](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blowback)** seems to fit

> *chiefly US* The unintended adverse results of a political action or situation:

---

PS - I can't remember where, but I've seen the phrase **Monkey's Paw** used for this. A reference to the WW Jacobs short story, in which supposedly good things happen with disastrous causes behind them.

Comment: Probably the Monkey's paw may fit, do you have any reference? The other examples lack the "disguise" part of the question.

Comment: @Josh61: Unfortunately not. Trying to find one.

Comment: I don't think Midas' gift was *in disguise*.  He got exactly what he wanted.  He was just rash and unthoughtful about the consequences of wish.

Comment: @A.Ellett: If you were the one who downvoted, you might want to consider that even if you disagree with my example, my suggestion still stands and should be the real reason to evaluate the answer here. Secondly, Midas got exactly what he wanted, which turned out to be a curse in disguise. The two aren't mutually exclusive. The very concept of curse in disguise is based on unforeseen bad consequences.

Comment: Blowback just generally refers just unforeseen, unwanted consequences of your own actions. Blowback does not appear to be a blessing. None of the examples really fit the actual question. This answer just goes off on its own tangent.

Comment: @CarlSmith: _Blowback does not appear to be a blessing._ Well, If you paid attention, you'd know the OP is asking for the OPPOSITE of a blessing.

Comment: Yes. But one that *appeared* to be a blessing, but that was a curse in disguise. And please don't shout at me.

Comment: @CarlSmith: Example: Govt. gives out millions of dollars to the poor. Bleassing. Now nobody wants to work and people can't hire anyone. Blowback. Clear?

Comment: @CarlSmith: You should only downvote if you consider the post unhelpful as a whole. Bear in mind `blowback` was my 3rd suggestion.

Comment: @TusharRaj - Let it go. Giving away millions of dollars is not a blessing, it's an act of charity. It may be a blessing for the people receiving the benefits. If they were fed, but then it turned out the food was rotten, and they all died of food poisoning, that'd work, but that's not blowback. And your other suggestions were equally poor, but had already been commented on. Genuinely, I'm not going to respond to this thread anymore. All the best for the next question dude.

Comment: @TusharRaj Why would you think I downvoted you?  I've never downvote anyone on this site.  And I wouldn't say that I disagree with you.  I was just saying that I don't think there was anything much *disguised* in Midas' gift.  I didn't mean to offend.  Sorry if I did.

Comment: I have a downvote???  Hmmm.  That's surprising to me.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Yup. Just the one though. The moment you cast another, you're profile can no longer back you up :)

Comment: @A.Ellett: BTW, I have to say I respect that. I've never DV'd either.

Comment: I'm going to guess that any downvotes on my part come from viewing this site from my iphone.

Answer (score 8):

The example of the OP seems to be the "opposite" of a *blessing in disguise* in the sense that a setback had **disastrous** as opposed to **beneficial** consequences. We might call such a setback a *disaster* *[in the making](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+making)*:

> in the process of happening
>
> *It became clear that this was a **disaster in the making** and we had no way of coping with it.*
>
> <sub>*Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
> University Press 2003.*</sub>

No one could have known it in advance, but in retrospect, that setback in car service was a ***disaster in the making*** for John Forbes Nash, Jr.

Comment: +1 for an interesting rationalization of "opposite". Most others are gravitating toward *curse in disguise*. The opposite of a phrase often produces a few bizarre permutations.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that **an unfortunate turn of events** accurately conveys what you're trying express to here.

> In an unfortunate turn of events, the car service that Dr John Nash had hired did not turn up. He hired a taxi cab which was involved in a crash, and both Dr Nash and his wife were killed.

Answer (score 2):

The example given is not the opposite of a blessing in disguise, it's **going from bad to worse**. So you could say, in Nash's case, that ["Murphy's law"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) applies:

> Anything that can possibly go wrong, will

or you could say that he

> jumped out of the frying pan into the fire

Answer (score 2):

Probably a [Trojan horse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trojan+horse) may convey the idea of something apparently good or positive but that in reality is dangerous:

(Classical Mythology. a gigantic hollow wooden horse, left by the Greeks upon their pretended abandonment of the siege of Troy. The Trojans took it into Troy and Greek soldiers concealed in the horse opened the gates to the Greek army at night and conquered the city.)

> - a person or thing intended to undermine or destroy from within.

( dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: +1, That's *actually* the opposite of a blessing in disguise, as the Trojan horse was a disaster disguised as a gift. It's not a great word to describe the example, but that's a pretty poor example.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly "the devil's in the details" or "there's no such thing as a free lunch" — though you'd need a more realistic example to see if they'd be appropriate in your case.

Both convey the idea of a thing that's good at first sight but may come with a catch (though the second doesn't necessarily mean it was bad on the whole).

"Every silver lining has its cloud" is a turn of phrase I've heard recently too (I'll try to find a source) — though not a common expression, it's easily understood & could be used here too, I think.

Answer (score 1):

As Tushar Raj's answer notes, one traditional way to describe a bad result that at first looks like a blessing is in connection with the warning "Be careful what you wish for" (sometimes completed with the phrase "because it might come true").

A familiar instance of this warning is in the cautionary fable from Aesop of "The Frogs Who Wished for a King." The public domain [*Aesop for Children*](http://www.read.gov/aesop/048.html) tells the fable this way:

> The Frogs were tired of governing themselves. They had so much freedom that it had spoiled them, and they did nothing but sit around croaking in a bored manner and wishing for a government that could entertain them with the pomp and display of royalty, and rule them in a way to make them know they were being ruled. No milk and water government for them, they declared. So they sent a petition to Jupiter asking for a king.
>
> Jupiter saw what simple and foolish creatures they were, but to keep them quiet and make them think they had a king he threw down a huge log, which fell into the water with a great splash. The Frogs hid themselves among the reeds and grasses, thinking the new king to be some fearful giant. But they soon discovered how tame and peaceable King Log was. In a short time the younger Frogs were using him for a diving platform, while the older Frogs made him a meeting place, where they complained loudly to Jupiter about the government.
>
> To teach the Frogs a lesson the ruler of the gods now sent a Crane to be king of Frogland. The Crane proved to be a very different sort of king from old King Log. He gobbled up the poor Frogs right and left and they soon saw what fools they had been. In mournful croaks they begged Jupiter to take away the cruel tyrant before they should all be destroyed.
>
> "How now!" cried Jupiter "Are you not yet content? You have what you asked for and so you have only yourselves to blame for your misfortunes."
>
> [Moral:] *Be sure you can better your condition before you seek to change.*

The moral is the conclusion of the *Aesop for Children* compilers. An equally valid moral might be "Be careful what you wish for—it might come true."

Answer (score 1):

You could says that it's a 
**Trojan Horse** - 
[TFD definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trojan+horse)

In my language there is even a better phrase, but I found out it doesn't directly translate into English / isn't well known.

It's something like **"fear the Danaans, even if bearing gifts!"**

More info here on wiki:
[Timeo Danaos et dona ferentes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeo_Danaos_et_dona_ferentes)

Comment: Trojan horse has already been suggested [by josh61](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/248469/44619), and the idiom/saying you propose is not an English one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - As we Americans say, don't let the bastards get you down. Use EL&U on your terms; leave if it's best for *you*. Stay if *you* want. But please know that you've been a bright light on this site, and always an example to me of what is good.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of "blessing in disguise" which, as you have correctly pointed out, means a perceived misfortune unexpectedly turning into a fortunate event, would be a seemingly fortunate event turning out to be quite unfortunate. In this case we could say "even roses have thorns", or "not everything is as it seems", or maybe something else, depending on the situation. But the situation you have described is not a fortunate event turning out bad, because the source of the misfortune - the car not showing up - is not a fortunate event in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Double edged sword is a phrase that could be used in this context to highlight that some things have two sides to them