The word for a serious situation that doesn't look it
Is there a term or word for a very serious situation that doesn't look serious, like a situation that needs or should have been attended to as early as possible but wasn't, because it doesn't seems that serious

Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248458/is-there-any-saying-or-idiom-to-describe-the-opposite-of-blessing-in-disguise

Elephant in the room?

unclear and present danger

insidious, pernicious? Not sure what you mean without more context.

Beware of calm waters!

A single word request should be accompanied by an example sentence.

For want of a nail ...

minefield (n.)

Figurative. A situation or subject presenting unseen hazards.
[OED online]


If you describe a situation as a minefield, you are emphasizing that
there are a lot of hidden dangers or problems, and where people need
to behave with care because things could easily go wrong.
Collins


A situation or subject that is very complicated and full of hidden
problems and dangers:
A legal minefield
A minefield of ethical problems
Cambridge



The journey from treachery to trust resembles a bumpy care ride in a
minefield, fraught with hidden dangers.
B. Janet Hibbs and ‎Karen J. Getzen; Try to See it My Way (2009)


Alessandra, Bella's mother, was more subtle, of course, with a diploma
in Reproach by Implication so that even the most innocuous topic of
conversation could be come a minefield, hidden dangers lurking
beneath every cautious tread.
Claire Calman; Love is a Four-Letter
Word (2020)


Once everything wrapped up in Wales, the trio went over to Spain to
check out the racecourse Simon had been telling them about. What he'd
called a garden spot turned out to be a minefield.  Sections of the
course weren't even paved.
Jim Gourley; The Race Within (2015)


The English language and local customs turned out to be a
minefield of difficulties. Lexical problems were numerous. I struggled with "weather," "wether," "whither," "whether," and
"wither." In history class, instead of "slavery" one had to say, "involuntary servitude." In place of "Civil War," it was "the War between the States."
Peter Suedfeld; Light from the Ashes (2001)


Deceptively safe/calm.
"Like blue skies in Yemen" - comes from the observation that more bombings/drone strikes are carried out on clear days due to better visibility.
Powder keg.
Subcritical - more of a corporate term.
Hidden threat.
Trojan horse.

This needs to be expanded to be a good answer. Why are some terms bolded and others not? Also, you should offer links/references, usage examples might help, and if necessary provide definitions.

Thanks for the feedback. I didn't bold any of them, someone edited it.

Such a state is sometimes referred to as a false peace. The expression may derive from a Bible verse (though it is a transparent metaphor) and is often used in Christian messages:

Jeremiah 6:14

They have healed also the hurt of the daughter of my people slightly, saying, 'Peace, peace' when there is no peace.

...
To be in a state of false peace is to be in a state of composure
— not of indifference, but of composure and satisfaction, in a belief
that all is well when all is not well.
                                                                                                                  [G. Fisk; Bible
Hub]

An example from a non-Christian source:

... after the Cold War, a realistic background for the rise of
democratic peace theory is that people have discovered  that after
World War II, especially  during the Cold  War, there  are few wars
between democratic countries. In fact, this is just a false peace
caused by the Cold War. Studies have proved that even among the
democracies during World War II, there were many wars ...                               Yuxuan Song: Is Democracy a Cause of Peace?]

though this is of course far more literal.
The only answer from the suggested duplicate that I feel fits well here is given by ScotM: 'a disaster in the making'                       (reference: Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms).
..................
The persons in such a dangerous position have a false sense of security.
